# How to do the Sticky session configuration in IBM HTTP SERVER?

Tags: java, configuration, cluster-computing

I have to do the sticky session configuration in IBM HTTP SERVER load balancer with clustered environment. So I searching for the document on net but no luck. So please if you have any doc, or useful links please share those.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

People do not typically do sticky sessions on the HTTP layers.    They either use IBM WEbSphere Edge Server OR a F5 with sticky in front of it.

The bigger question is why do you want to use sticky session?  If you configured WAS correctly and using WAS ND with session clustering, there is no need for sticky session because all the WAS nodes would have access to the session data.